# How to implement call merge,waiting and call conference using android.telecom.InCallService

Tags: android, telephonymanager

I am using `android.telecom.InCallService` in one of my of projects. It gives all telephony states excellently, but once you implement this service you need to create your own dialler, which can handle all call features i.e. call merge, conferencing, call waiting, etc.

Any link or suggestion to implement call waiting, merge and conference would be great help.

Answer (score 1):

I've only found how to hold a call, in this repository: 
 [CustomPhoneDialer](https://github.com/Abror96/CustomPhoneDialer). See the InCallService, on the method onCallAdded (Override), create a new OngoingCall.

```
    onCallAdded(Call call){
    ....
    new OngoingCall().setCall(call)
    ....
    }
```

In OngoingCall class you need to create methods that you go to use in your activity like answer, reject, etc.. And one of you need, hold/unhold:

```
public class OngoingCall {

public static BehaviorSubject<Integer> state = BehaviorSubject.create();
private static Call call;

private Object callback = new Call.Callback() {
    @Override
    public void onStateChanged(Call call, int newState) {
        super.onStateChanged(call, newState);
        state.onNext(newState);
    }
};

public final void setCall(@Nullable Call value) {
    if (call != null) {
        call.unregisterCallback((Call.Callback)callback);
    }

    if (value != null) {
        value.registerCallback((Call.Callback)callback);
        state.onNext(value.getState());
    }
    call = value;
}

public void answer() {
    assert call != null;
    call.answer(VideoProfile.STATE_AUDIO_ONLY);
}

public void hangup() {
    assert call != null;
    call.disconnect();
}
public void hold(){
    assert call != null;
    call.hold();
}

public void unHold(){
    assert call != null;
    call.unhold();
}
....
}
```

And in the activity, in a button listener use these methods:

```
private OngoingCall ongoingCall;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_call);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    ongoingCall = new OngoingCall();
    disposables = new CompositeDisposable();

    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD
            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);

    number = Objects.requireNonNull(getIntent().getData()).getSchemeSpecificPart();
}

@OnClick(R.id.answer)
public void onAnswerClicked() {
    ongoingCall.answer();
}

@OnClick(R.id.hangup)
public void onHangupClicked() {
    ongoingCall.hangup();
}

@OnClick(R.id.hold)
public void onHoldClicked(){
    ongoingCall.hold();
}

@OnClick(R.id.unhold)
public void onUnHoldClicked(){
    ongoingCall.unHold();
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Joel , I have almost solved all states including conference. I will post the solution in coming few days after I test them  .

Comment: Thanks to you, if you publish here the solution would do me a favor, because I can not merge the calls or create the conference. I try a lot of things, I've seen the official documentation but without success.

Comment: I will do it soon Joel , It is under development not fully ready .

Comment: Did you found a solution? Are you investigating?

Comment: Hi Joel , please add me on skype   kk.mca2009@gmail.com will discuss and will with you .

Comment: I have  not received ur invite . pls send me ur id .

Comment: jgarcia@offshoretech.net or lintz_18@hotmail.com

Comment: There is some serious problem either with ur account or skype. I have sent u request long back but looks you have not received, I can still see my request in pending state .

Comment: It doesn't work, if you want send me an email to joelgar7@gmail.com this is my personal email

Comment: Can we talk by hangouts

Comment: @Jeol Garcia: I have implemented conference merge also.. 2nd call will only merge if state of 2nd call changed to STATE_ACTIVE.. Let me know still if you are facing problem, I will try to create github project for this.

Comment: Ei guys! Thank you for your contribution, I am still working on this, if we can share things better than better, my team and I will get back to the conferences shortly if I have something if it works I will share it with you!